# I want to install Mono on MacOSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, mono, osx-yosemite

I want to install Mono on MacOSX Yosemite.

I installed it but I tried type "mono", terminal said "command not found". So it looks like it failed to install it properly?

How to install Mono properly on MacOSX Yosemite?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to install software on OS X is to use a package manager like [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). To install Homebrew open a Terminal and paste in the following command

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then to install Mono you can simply use

```
brew install mono
```

which will install version 4.2.0.179.

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of mono comply to the "El Capitan" requirements of not installing anything into **/usr/bin** and thus now **/usr/local/bin** is used. I am not sure which mono 4.x release that started in...

But I would assume that you do not have /usr/local/bin in your path(?), try:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
which mono
which mcs
```

In my case, I have 4.2.0 installed:

```
$ which mono
/usr/local/bin/mono
$ which mcs
/usr/local/bin/mcs
$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.0 (explicit/2701b19 Mon Aug 31 09:57:28 EDT 2015)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
$ cat `which mcs`
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.0/bin
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/pkgconfig:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.0/lib/pkgconfig:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.0/share/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
exec /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.0/bin/mono $MONO_OPTIONS /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.0/lib/mono/4.5/mcs.exe "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew is certainly an option.

Another way is to download the [Mono .pkg file](http://www.mono-project.com/download/), run the .pkg and accept the license to install Mono on the Mac. The stable Mono versions are provided on the [Mono website](http://www.mono-project.com/download/)

Comment: Thank you!!I installed Mono.I'm so happy!!